# 'select into' statement not working in mysql store procedure with cursor

Tags: mysql, database, cursor, procedure

Here is the issue: temprequest is the table where i fetch rows from.
I look up the deliverableId column of deliverable table based on the temprequest table while fetching. therefore i use a select into statement. but the variable where I put the looked up value is only working for the first row fetched.

The 'Begin end' block:

```
DECLARE no_more_rows BOOLEAN;
DECLARE nr_rows INT DEFAULT 0;  
DECLARE loop_cntr INT DEFAULT 0;

declare delId int;

declare vtname varchar(200);
declare tversion varchar(200);
declare custId int;
declare prod varchar(200);

DECLARE c_temp CURSOR FOR select tname, version,BuID,BuprodName from temprequest;
SET no_more_rows = False;

OPEN c_temp;
select FOUND_ROWS() into nr_rows;

the_loop:LOOP
    FETCH c_temp into vtname,tversion,custId, prod;
    IF no_more_rows THEN            
        LEAVE the_loop;
    END IF;
    -- statements for each request record
    Set delId= (SELECT deliverableId  
                FROM deliverable 
                WHERE deliverable.Product_prodName =vtname AND deliverable.version = tversion);
    INSERT INTO request VALUES (delId, custId, prod);               
    SET loop_cntr = loop_cntr + 1;

END LOOP the_loop;
CLOSE c_temp;
```

Comment: `no_more_rows`  is not used in this code... Shouldn't it be: `DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET no_more_rows = TRUE;` OR `no_more_rows = if nr_rows = loop_cntrl then TRUE else FALSE`?

Comment: it is used, no_more_rows is set automatically to false when there are no more rows to read in the table.

Comment: actually the problem is the 'select into' statement.

Comment: sorry a little mistake above: "it is used, no_more_rows is set automatically to TRUE when there are no more rows to read in the table"

Comment: Usually, cursor runs for the same row, when there is no jump to the next row, or may be your select statemtent for cursoe definition returns same rows? Is there anything else this cursor does? You can accomplish the same thing without cursor too.

Comment: i already test it just by displaying the data contained in the temprequest like this: select delId,vtname,tversion,custId, prod

Comment: it worked fine displaying each row but the variable delId was giving me some trouble. its not set every time in my loop. i'm confused!. please provide the other solution you think of. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The no_more_rows variable gets set to true if any query within the cursor doesn't fetch any result. In your case if the following query doesn't fetch any result, even in that case `no_more_rows` will evaluated as `true`.

```
SELECT deliverableId  
FROM deliverable 
WHERE deliverable.Product_prodName =vtname AND deliverable.version = tversion
```

Solution for this is to set no_more_rows to false at the end of the cursor, so that even if it evaluates to true during cursor execution, it will be reset and will be exited only when there are no rows returned by the cursor query.

```
he_loop:LOOP
    FETCH c_temp into vtname,tversion,custId, prod;
    IF no_more_rows THEN            
        LEAVE the_loop;
    END IF;
    -- statements for each request record
    Set delId= (SELECT deliverableId  
                FROM deliverable 
                WHERE deliverable.Product_prodName =vtname AND deliverable.version = tversion);
    INSERT INTO request VALUES (delId, custId, prod);               
    SET loop_cntr = loop_cntr + 1;
    SET no_more_row = false
END LOOP the_loop;
```

Comment: I find a cleaner way to handle this is to declare the SELECT INTO within a nested BEGIN/END block

Comment: SET no_more_row = false; saved my life. The reason is SELECT .. INTO also sets its value to TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish the same without cursor use **(UPDATED**):

```
INSERT INTO request 
SELECT 
    deliverable.deliverableId   as delId,
    qwe.BuID            as custId,
    qwe.BuprodName          as prod

FROM deliverable 
inner join 
(select tname, version, BuID,BuprodName 
from temprequest) 
    as qwe (tname, version, BuID,BuprodName) 
        on deliverable.Product_prodName = qwe.vtname 
       AND deliverable.version = qwe.tversion
```

I've just realised that `BuID` and `BuprodName` are constants here and not used anywhere besides insert statement.

Comment: thank you for sharing but its not working. the subquerry returns many rows. and that is because in temprequest I have many duplications (this is a table withouth a PK) just for reading data to populate the real one. isn't there any other way perhaps?.